# Asp.net webpage has a lot of blank space at bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net

My asp.net webpage has a ton of white space at the bottom of a div within a content page, and I have no idea where its coming from.  There are NOT a ton of
`<br />`
's or &nbsp's in the source view.  How can I find out where the space is coming from and correct?

Could this element be taking up space???

```
   <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: 10000; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: 246px; position: absolute; height: 320px;" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" id="ctl00_ctl00_PageContent_PageContent_cboTurnOver_OptionList"><li>&nbsp;</li><li>Aaron Ament - 034  </li><li>Aaron Stack - 235  </li><li>Accounting  - OA   </li><li>Adam Kauth - 289  </li><li>Admin  - 481  </li><li>Aimee Tatge - 149  </li><!--Over 100 entries removed for security and brevity--><li>Zeddie Roshelle - 346  </li></ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the source or a link?

Comment: Not practical.  I really just need some general guidance on finding the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) inspect the whitespace to see which element it is in your html. Or in Chrome right click on it and select inspect element. The relevant source will be highlighted for you.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this a style related item.  The "Developer Toolbar" for FireFox is a great plugin for this type of thing as it allows you to inspect the document and see what is taking up the space.

Comment: Hmmmm... this is bizarre, when I view the page I see the whitespace, but then when I click on Forms --> Display Form Details the whitespace diappears.  I don't know what this means.

Answer (score 1):

Look through the CSS style sheet for a "[min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_min-height.asp)" rule being applied.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything like that in the CSS.

Comment: Try the Firefox Web Developer Toolbar to identify the area in question: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/

Comment: I see that Mitchell has already suggested this - click CSS -> View Style Information, and click on the page section giving you the problem. This will bring up the CSS rule in play.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any whitespace in your viewpage at the bottom.  If you also see nothing in the source - check your css, as you could have something funky going on there.

Comment: @MunkinPhD- What do you mean by "viewpage"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that term.

Answer (score 0):

Check your page with internet explorer developer tool or firefox firebug
and look for

and  tag margins
with firebug you can manupulate the html code to see what happen on the fly
[Firebug download](http://getfirebug.com)

also you can send me your online version I should have a look at it for you

Comment: CANNOT BE THAT CONTROL AS IT IS HIDDEN (DISPLAY:NONE)